# Error when trying to run tests for python/django written in PyCharm

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I am writing tests for a django program and I keep getting this error when I run it through the command line (Windows): django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.

When I try running one of the test functions through PyCharm it says: Error running 'Unittests for test_models.UserTest': Can't get importable name for PyFile:test_models.py. Is it a python file in project?

I know the problem has something to do with configuration settings, but I don't understand how to set these up properly.  I'm relatively new to PyCharm so any help would be much appreciated.  Thank you.

I tried asking this question on the PyCharm forums, and I was told to ask elsewhere, because if the problem is occurring when I run tests through the command line and my IDE, it's probably not just a problem with the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

To run a test case for Django view, first, you need to write a test file like below

```
from django.test import TestCase

class YourTestClass(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        # print("setUpTestData: Run once to set up non-modified data for all class methods.")
        pass
```

Then you should press CTRL+Alt+R together to run manage.py in Pycharm and finally, you just need to write `test appname` in the console.

Comment: I'm running tests for Django models, not views.  I already have the tests written and in a test file.  When I go to run them, I get the error that I posted above.  This doesn't help me with the error.